# I keep getting a certification error in my Quarkus application trying to connect to mongodb at IBM Cloud

Tags: java, mongodb, ibm-cloud, quarkus

I developed a simple Quarkus application connecting to a mongodb at IBM Cloud.

But I keep getting this certification error:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.ibm.jsse2.g.a(g.java:58)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ba.a(ba.java:38)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ba.a(ba.java:101)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ba.a(ba.java:62)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.y$c.a(y$c.java:166)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.y$c.a(y$c.java:10)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.y$c.consume(y$c.java:6)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.p.consume(p.java:43)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.Z.a(Z.java:73)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bf$a$b.a(bf$a$b.java:2)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bf$a$b.run(bf$a$b.java:3)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:770)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bf$a.run(bf$a.java:26)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.handleTask(TlsChannelImpl.java:271)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.handshakeLoop(TlsChannelImpl.java:599)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.handshake(TlsChannelImpl.java:554)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.doHandshake(TlsChannelImpl.java:529)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.handshake(TlsChannelImpl.java:511)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.impl.TlsChannelImpl.write(TlsChannelImpl.java:385)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.ClientTlsChannel.write(ClientTlsChannel.java:181)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.writeHandlingTasks(AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.java:553)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.doWrite(AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.java:501)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.access$400(AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.tlschannel.async.AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup$6.run(AsynchronousTlsChannelGroup.java:459)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.a(h.java:120)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.b(h.java:5)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:10)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bq.a(bq.java:32)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bq.a(bq.java:70)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.bq.checkServerTrusted(bq.java:10)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.y$c.a(y$c.java:99)
        ... 22 more
```

What could it be ?

I already tried to generate a keystore, but it did not work.

Comment: On the Manage section of the service's details, you should see a button for under  "Authenticate server identity" to download a certificate to use when connecting to your Mongo instance.

Comment: Is there any way that I do not need to do this certificate validation ?